# WooCommerce product import is slow, how to speed it up?

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I wish to import 1,000,000 products into WordPress (Products are in the CSV file)

It can take up to two hours to import 1,000 items. If I attempted to import 1 million items, it would take approximately 83 days!

My products don't include images. (There are no image columns)

Why is the rate of product import into WordPress so slow? How do I speed things up?

Comment: There's a plugin, [Index WP MySQL For Speed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/), that installs faster database indexes. Users have reported improvements in Woo import performance when using it.

Comment: @O.Jones Jones I tested this plugin. No change in speed

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the capacity of your server but in whatever scenario it should not take 83 days to import! Should be able to do it by 20min ~2hours.

Please follow the below tricks and check if it is working for you [assuming low capacity server/laptop/internet speed] -

1. Split some data from csv file and make some csv filse consisting 1k, 3k, 5k, 10k  product items.
2. Open multiple tab 5~10 and go to import interface
3. Uploads 1k csv files in all tab and hit import [Note: do not use file with same product info :D]
4. Now try with 3k, then 5k, then 10k to find out the choking point of your device capacity.
5. If 5k file is takes too long/fail but 3k file does ok, in such case try with 4k files.
6. Assuming 3k file is working fine for your device with 10 tab and importing taking 3~5 min then importing 1 mill will take ~20 mins.

** You can use csv splitter from internet

Comment: I've tried all these methods. But the problem was not solved

Comment: @seyedrezabazyar - would you be able to share the csv file? if so I will first check on my local and debug it for a solution, you can find my contacts in my profile.